# checking if user has an access token with lucadegasperi oath 2 server

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

I've the following issue i come cross with. im busy with making an Api with Laravel 5 and the goal of this API is to communicate with an IOS.

What i want to achive is to check with the oauth access process if the user already has an Access token ,"and if the the token is still valid. If so well let the user authorise himself, otherwise if his token is expired refresh his token and sign him in.

The current solution is that i query the user and check if the users id the same as the owner_id.

Is it possible to do this in an more elegant way?

Thank u very much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're doing it right.

Based on the SQL tables structure the only way you can get the info you need is by joining oauth_sessions and oauth_access_tokens through session_id.

You might wanna make sure that the owner_type says 'user', owner_id is equal to the ID of your user and the tokens aren't expired yet (expire_time).